# App crashing on api 19, but not 24

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

When running the appliction on device API 19 and open (Search Activity) the app is crashing, But when running the app on device 24 API the app working 100% without problems.

**This code XML of Search Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.abdullrahman.eng.myapptest.Search">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageVIew"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/se_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageVIew"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/kite_one"
    android:text="Search for people"
    android:textColor="@color/bluePrim"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/se_input"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:background="@drawable/se_back"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/se_bt"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="@font/kite_one"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="#95989A" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/results_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView> </LinearLayout>
```

**and this here my logcat when click on button to open Search Activity**

```
02-10 16:50:15.260 18502-18502/com.abdullrahman.eng.myapptest W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415f6c80) 

02-10 16:50:32.080 18502-18502/com.abdullrahman.eng.myapptest I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18502 SIG: 9 –
```

Comment: 1) Give us all of the logcat 2) Move all v24 fonts, colors, and drawables over to v19

Comment: post full logcat and the line where it is redirecting you so that we can help you.

Comment: You are properly using a newer API on an older platform. Check all compile warnings.

Comment: this all logcat
https://pastebin.com/wk6Zti8k

Comment: @cricket_077 I havent file drawables v19!